# Parsing of JSON to Oracle

Tags: json, plsql

I have a nested JSON in the format like `[{"name":debasis},{"Age":21}]`.

How can I pass the JSON to PL/SQL procedure and print that JSON inside that procedure?

Comment: See http://sourceforge.net/projects/pljson/ , http://reseau.erasme.org/pl-sql-library-for-JSON?lang=en and https://github.com/doberkofler/PLSQL-JSON

Comment: I think this json is not correct. Maybe I'm wrong, but I believe `debasis` should be in double quotes.